# pop up window opens fullscreen in firefox though sizes are given

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup, size

I'm opening a Popup, it opens in internet explorer and mozilla firefox. But firefox ignores the given sizes, so a fullscreen popup is created.

Following code:

```
<a href="agb.html" target="_blank" onclick="return popup(this.href);">linkname</a>
```

Following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup (url) {
fenster = window.open(url, "Popup", "width=640,height=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");
fenster.focus();
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Stupid thought on my part, but have you checked your Firefox settings to check whether you have disabled 'move or resize existing windows'?

Comment: No, I did not, i just checked the "block popups" function. Where to find this specific option? Anyway the solution are the parameters "top" and "left", with them it works, without the window shows fullscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have on a dev site which I know at works in Firefox (actually it's the only thing *I* have tested it on.
I don't know too much about js, so I'm sure I got this from the web somewhere- so hopefully it follows correct practices and what not.

```
// js:
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
url,'popUpWindow','height=390,width=350,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}

</script>

// link: edit: an onclick event should be used instead, but I'm leaving my original code.
<a href="Javascript:newPopup('/url/');">Link text</a>
```

Comment: This works, but I still do not get why. For me it looks exactly the same... I will further investigate... ;-) Probably one of the parameters has to be set...

Comment: it's not the same at all -.- he wrote the javascript stuff in the href tag and did not use a onclick event .. so users without javascript wont be able to click that link..

Comment: good point Walialu. I had this in a project I did a while ago, and now that you bring it up I realized I now use onclicks (check if it works in IE!). Also, I work for internal projects, so I know only if it works on the software we use, and for instance I know all our computer use cookies, js, firefox or chrome etc. It's good to hear about cases that effect users with limited access or whatnot.

Comment: I only copied the params of his window.open function and preserved my onclick variant. the solution are the parameters "top" and "left", with them it works, without the window shows fullscreen. Kind of understandable, but internet explorer is just fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem with a form submitted to a popup.
I have

```
<form name ="printView" method ="post" action="printOnly.php" target="popUp"
             onsubmit="popup(this);" style="display:inline!important;">
```

(the style is to get the form on the same line as another form)

And the popup function is

```
function popup(form) {
    window.open('','formpopup', 'view text',
                'height=700,width=640,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes'
    );
    form.target = 'formpopup';
    view.focus(this);
}
```

As you can see I have tried the top and left options, but my popup still opens at the same size as the main window, and the scrollbar, toolbar, menubar, directories and location settings are disregarded, I get only the location bar no matter what I set their values to.
PS. I checked Firefox popup preferences and they are all allowed.

Comment: I think the "view.focus(this)" is incorrect, because you are giving the form itself as object, but you want the popup to be focussed or?

Comment: And your url param is empty... on purpose?

Comment: you're right, I want the pop to be focussed. The URL parameter is empty because the function is used to load different urls in different forms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the display property of your popup to be either `display: block;` or `display: inline-block` for your width and height dimensions to take effect.

Comment: but my popup is a window, does the window object exist for css?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp <- there is no attribute like display or css for window... but your idea did not sound bad at all. Thank you anyway :-)

Comment: No problem. I'm assuming since you looked through that page that you saw the resizeTo() function. Just out of curiosity, does that solve your problem?

Comment: No, I did not try it but the solution are the parameters "top" and "left", with them it works, without the window shows fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="agb.html" target="_blank" onclick="popup(this.href);return false;">linkname</a>
```

will do what you want ;)

Comment: does have absolutely the same effect like my notation :-/ But I found that the solution are the parameters "top" and "left", with them it works, without the window shows fullscreen