# How to Prevent this opening in full screen and Add Scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Hi I just want to ask how can i make this pop up not in full screen and with Scroll bar this line of code

```
<a href="/Hire/HireDetails?Id=' + ID + '" onclick="window.open(this.href,height=850,width=1200);return false""><span style="font-size: 12px !important">View Profile</span></a>
```

this opens in Fullscreen mode in Firefox and the scrollbar is  not seen ..

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873887/pop-up-window-opens-fullscreen-in-firefox-though-sizes-are-given

Comment: Instead of opening a new browser window and annoying your users, if you want to overlay more information you could consider a [modal window overlay](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/)

Comment: Popup is a no-go nowadays. Ast @misterManSam told you, use a modal window instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.open("","","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=650,height=600");
```

Comment: not working sir.. it just open it in the current window

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.vikaskottari.tk" onclick="event.preventDefault();window.open(this.href,'','location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,height=1200,width=1200');">
<span style="font-size: 12px !important">View Profile</span></a>
```